# How to get started with d3js examples using xampp?

Tags: javascript, installation, xampp, d3.js

I am deeply impressed by all the cool stuff that is possible with the modern javascript libraries such as protovis and d3js. As an ecologist I have plenty of data that would be perfect for these advanced visualization techniques. Sadly, I am lost already after downloading the d3js library. :(

I read on http://d3js.org that one has to setup a localhost in order to get the examples running. I have a xampp system installed on a windows 7 system. Localhost/xampp tells me that everything is fine but still I cannot get most of the examples running. For example "albers" shows only a grey box. The example "bar" does run as it should (I suppose).

Could anyone give me a hint how to get started correctly on windows 7 ? Links to tutorials are much appreciated. If I find out the right way, I will make my own tutorial for the world.

I know that my question sounds boring and unpleasant since it is the absolute beginner question and I am very sorry for that but I really want to work with d3js because I have sooo many good (?) ideas.

thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you are doing wrong here. I just downloaded the [zip file](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/zipball/master) and unzipped it to `C:\path\to\xampp\htdocs\d3examples`, so that this folder now contains folders like `src`, `lib`, `examples` etc. Accessing `http://localhost/d3examples/examples/albers/albers.html` in Chrome and Firefox shows up the correct map. Did try to open the `albers.html` file directly by double-clicking and get a blank page.

Comment: now it works, thank you very much for your good explanation! I was not aware to unzip into the htdocs. This means, for some of the examples it needs the "localhost/example.html" address. thanks! If I could, I would check your answer as the most correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the examples in the d3 sample library may produce errors in certain browsers when you try to run static files locally. Mike suggests that you run python's simplehttpserver while browsing the samples.

See instructions here:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888
```

Comment: thank you. I tried this earlier but did not know what to do. After reading the comment of mtariq I understood that I simply have to type in `localhost:8888/d3examples/`... works as well! Great!

Comment: ah, I noticed that I only works without :8888 so only the browser should read `localhost/d3examples/examples/albers/albers.html`

Answer (score 9):

d3.js is a **client side** JavaScript library so you don't need any servers in the background. To begin use static files. Here is a short example:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first d3.js</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="mySVG"></div>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
    <script>
      var svg = d3.select("#mySVG")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr("height", 200)

      svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", 50)
        .attr("y", 50)
        .attr("class", "text")
        .text("d3.js is awesome")
    </script>
  </body>
```

and a style.css for styling:

```
.text {
  fill: blue;
}
```

Open `index.html` in the browser and you should see a blue text saying "d3.js is awesome". More helpful tutorials are:

- http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/
- http://christopheviau.com/d3_tutorial/
- http://www.recursion.org/d3-for-mere-mortals/
- http://www.janwillemtulp.com/2011/03/20/tutorial-introduction-to-d3/

and of course

- https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials

Comment: Dear Mirco, many thanks for your illustrative example. I understand that a link to the source at dj3s.org would be enough already. I will now carefully read the proposed tutorials.